# Way to have *ngFor loop repeat itself x number of times

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Currently working on an app that calculates golf handicap so it's a simple form that takes 5 inputs of type number (18 hole score, 9 hole score, course rating, slope rating & score differential) however I will need that grouping of 5 inputs anywhere from 3-20 times (so anywhere from 45 - 100 total inputs).

Just to get it to work I haven't done any form related elements in the HTML (i.e. labels, id, name, etc.) so I am currently just using an h4 and an input to get it to work and then i'll go back and add all the extra form related stuff.

The way I am doing it now is I am using an *ngFor to loop through to give me the name of the field and then I have an input type number both inside a div so one grouping of those 5 names & inputs comes through but I want to know is there a way/how can I get it so there will be these 5 inputs repeated 3 times (instead of just repeating the HTML 3 separate times which seems excessive)?  The reason for the initial 3 is that in order to calculate I need at least 3 'groupings' worth of data to do the math.

I will then need to add a button so users can add groupings for more inputs but I figure lets start here and i'll worry about adding later.  I decided to go with the Template drive approach since it's such a simple form compared to a Reactive form.  I know Reactive forms seem to be a better choice for dynamic forms but this form isn't so much 'dynamic' as I just want to be able to add more of the same things when users click a button.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let fun of test; let i = index">
      <h4>{{fun}} : {{i + 1}}</h4>
      <input type="number">
  </div>
```

TS:

```
  test: Array <any> = [
    '18 Hole Score',
    '9 Hole Score',
    'Course Rating',
    'Slope Rating',
    'Score Differential'
  ]
```

This is what it looks like, so I would want to be able to copy and repeat this group of 5 inputs a total of 3 times (and then have on a button click the ability to add a new extra grouping)
[image: Display of screen]

Comment: Use a FormArray. Sure you need know the value of the "inputs". NOTE: in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75230675/angular-data-binding-repeated/75230971#75230971) you have an example of formArray of RomGroup, but there're a lot of examples in SO and in another places.

Comment: Would it make more sense if I went with a reactive approach opposed to template driven?  I figured since the form was so simple template would be better but it looks like to add things more dynamically then reactive would be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your code inside another *ngFor. You can get a number input and make array repeatTimes from that number.

For example:

```
<div *ngFor="let repeat of repeatTimes">

  <div *ngFor="let fun of test; let i = index">
      <h4>{{fun}} : {{i + 1}}</h4>
      <input type="number">
  </div>
</div>
```

TS preferably in ngOnInit:

```
let repeatCount = 5;
let repeatTimes = [];
for(let i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
{
  repeatTimes.push(i);
}
```

Comment: If I do it this way it works however from a form perspective each input matches between each group (i.e. 18 hole score in each grouping is mirrored because I am just looping/repeating and not creating new/individual fields for each group)

Comment: Then I will suggest using Reactive Form with Form Arrays. You can easily add + - functionality to add or remove groups easily.